# Jquery range selection previous element on contenteditable="false"

Tags: jquery, contenteditable, backspace

I have this snippet:

```
<div contenteditable="true"> father
      <a contenteditable="false" href="#"> myLink </a>
</div>
```

My problem is that if I place caret after

```
</a>
```

and I try to backspace for remove myLink html tag, It doesn't work in firefox, but it works in chorme, opera, safari and explorer.
Other hand if in firefox I select

```
<a contenteditable="false" href="#"> myLink </a>
```

and then delete it with backspace it works!.

Possible workaround It is range selecting of the element

```
<a contenteditable="false" href="#"> myLink </a>
```

programmatically when user digit backspace key.

How can I do this in jquery?
If the caret cursor is after

```
</a>
```

and user digit backspace I want select

```
<a contenteditable="false" href="#"> myLink </a>
```

and remove that node.

Answer (score 1):

Add a span tag with contenteditable=true like below,

`<a contenteditable="false" href="#"><span contenteditable="true"> myLink </span></a>`

Check [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/Qr3qL/) here,

I tested it in FF, IE 8 and Chrome and was able to remove with backspace, but the user experiance is different in FF and other browsers.

I am not sure if this is the best way to do it.

**Edit:** Seems like this is already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177958/how-to-delete-an-html-element-inside-a-div-with-attribute-contenteditable)