# How to find out if img-tag is left of the caret node in a html editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, html-editor

I am using a html editor to edit content. Now i need to make sure a very special kind of element does not get deleted (images with a special class).

For the use cases of a non-collapsed selection/range with BACKSPACE, DELETE, CTRL + X/CMD + X i found a solution, but i am still looking for a solution to the case that the selection/range is not collapsed and the next Backspace will delete one of my special images.

**How can i detect if the next Backspace/Delete will remove one of those img-tags ?**

Example: CARET marks the caret/cursor position. If Backspace will be pushed next the image will get removed. How can i detect this case?

```
<p>Some Text <b>here <img class="my class" src="..."/></b>CARET some text</p>
```

Comment: You seem to have two cases to deal with: when the caret is to the right of the image, and when you have a non-empty selection. Are you interested in both?

Comment: no, i got a working solution for the non-empty selection. the problem is the case when the caret is left/right of the image and Backspace/Delete could get pushed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below detects elements around caret with `onkeyup` (and `onselectionchange`), but it's for IE only. Maybe it can be "translated" to jQuery.

```
function detectClass(){
    var range, parentR, parentL;
    range = document.selection.createRange();
    range.moveStart('character',1);
    range.moveEnd('character',1);
    parentR = range.parentElement();
    range.moveStart('character',-2);
    range.moveEnd('character',-2);
    parentL = range.parentElement();
    if (parentR.className == 'special'){/* special on right */}
    if (parentL.className == 'special'){/* special on left */}
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the case of checking whether the caret is next to an image, here's an answer of mine to a similar question. It relies on Rangy for IE < 9 support but can be trivially made to not rely on Rangy.

The answer only considers backspace but could easily be adapted to work for <kbd>Delete</kbd> as well.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10020476/96100

Comment: hmm, i do not know exactly what to do here - there can even be more than one of those img-tags. can you please describe a bit clearer what needs to be done?

Comment: @Thariama: I'll look more closely later. By the way, you may not be able to prevent your images being deleted in all situations: some browsers have delete options on Edit and context menus that you won't be able to detect before it's too late.

Comment: i know about those special cases when i cannot detect anything (deletion and cutting using context menu), but fortunately i am able to blame the user in this case :)

Comment: i am not able to get it working - can you have a closer look?

Comment: @Thariama: Sorry, I really am planning to do something about this, but I'm struggling for time and keep forgetting. Maybe at the weekend.

Comment: i have been able to develop something of my own (using parts of your code). i will post my solution when i find the time