# undesirable bulk delete of non-editable custom elements within contenteditable div, in iOS Webkit

Tags: javascript, html, ios, webkit

I am trying to find the solution for a delete problem that I am facing in iOS/UIWebView while deleting a custom html element which is having its contenteditable attribute overridden to false, while its parent is a div tag with contenteditable value set as true.

```
<div id="editable" contenteditable="true>
    <mycustomtag id="uuid1" contenteditable="false"> .... </mycustomtag><br>
    <mycustomtag id="uuid2" contenteditable="false"> .... </mycustomtag><br>
    <mycustomtag id="uuid3" contenteditable="false"> .... </mycustomtag><br>
</div>
```

I wish to delete one of the mycustomtag elements within the div tag, by placing the caret next to it. But, when I delete the last custom tag with uuid3, **ALL** of the mycustomtag elements are getting deleted, instead of just one. I don't see any valid reason of why this is happening.

I referred to this link : [How to delete an HTML element inside a div with attribute contentEditable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177958/how-to-delete-an-html-element-inside-a-div-with-attribute-contenteditable)
where similar problem is been addressed, but this does not seem to be solving my problem. Any help ?