# contenteditable = false in firefox browser

Tags: javascript, firefox, contenteditable, incompatibility

I have a problem with firefox. Cursor jumps into div where i have set an attribute contenteditable = false when i click backspace, instead of deleting whole div which I excpect (works on chrome and safari) The structure:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
     <div contenteditable="false">
        ### CONTENT ###
     </div> 
</div>
```

Also each nested HTML component has an attribute contenteditable="false"

How to solve this incompatibility problem?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this seems to be a known [Firefox Bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=685445)...

I've used this [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30574622/5683888) to counter that problem. It detects backspaces and checks if the element right before the caret has `contenteditable` set to `false`. If so it removes it. Works like a charm.

Comment: Sorry @Tiw I'm new to this. I've just added a solution I found and used.